# What are the correct types for an Event and event.target when trying to access a value from an input in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, types, angular6

I have an input that looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="value" (click)="doSomething($event)">
```

This works fine and the function `doSomething` is called correctly:

```
doSomething(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    console.log(value);
}
```

Now I want to add the correct types and silly me, I expected this to work:

```
doSomething(event: Event) {
    const target: HTMLInputElement = event.target;
    const value: String = target.value;
    console.log(value);
}
```

I nearly tried all combinations of:

- using `MouseEvent` and `EventEmitter` instaed of `Event`
- using `target: EventTarget = event.target;` (working, but fails on the next line)
- using `target: Element = event.target;` (not working)
- using `target: HTMLElement = event.target;` (not working)
- using `target: HTMLInputElement = event.target;` (not working)

I also tried `event.srcElement` instead of `event.target`, which works with 'Element' but fails on the next line, becuase it's not an `HTMLInputElement`.

---

These are the error messages:

> Type 'EventTarget' is not assignable to type 'Element'.

… and …

> Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement'.

… and –

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element'.

---

*What is the correct way?*

---

<sup>I know this is working without the strict types and I know that I could use a `ViewChild`. But somehow, I want this to work as well.</sup>

Comment: On the line `const value = option.value`, what is option? Where is it coming from?

Comment: @user184994 Sorry, that was a typo, during simplification - I've fixed it.

Comment: Technically not a duplicate, because he's asking about the `event.target`.

Comment: @user184994 I am aware of this question - I don't think that it's really a dulplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click event is of type `MouseEvent`. This includes clicks, double clicks, mouse up and mouse down.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent

The *target* of an event is of type `EventTarget`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget

A *target* can be an element, window or document. You can try to infer which one it is by looking at what properties it has, but if it is `<input (click)="...">` you know it's an element.

You have to *cast* it to the type you want.

```
 const target: HTMLInputElement = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
```